# Objectum quod vs objectum quo

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

Could use some help on this translation, especially the bolded sections.

Objectum huius amoris est duplex: **quod, & quo.** **Objectum quod** est creatura sive homo, qui creatura Dei est. **Objectum quo** sive formale est justitia. Primum ergo objectum huius amoris est justitia, quam Deus gratam per se habet, **& propter quam creaturam sibi gratam habere vult: quia in ea, tanquam bono sibi proximo conveniente & amico, delectatur sibique complacet.**

The object of this love is twofold: the **object quod** and **object quo**. The object quod is the creature or man, who is the creature of God. Therefore, the first object of this love is righteousness which is pleasing to God in itself and **on account of which He wills to regard the creature grateful to Himself, because it greatly pleases Him and He takes pleasure in the creature, as in a good neighbor agreeing with himself and a friend.**

Answer (score 2):

The *objectum quod* is "the thing that is loved", and the *objectum quo* is "the thing for which it is loved".